# MongoDB: error with $divide and $multiply

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm creating a MongoDB aggregation pipeline and I'm stuck at this stage:

```
        $group: {
            _id: {checkType: "$_id.checkType", resultCode: "$_id.resultCode"},
            count: { $sum: "$count" },
            ctv: { $sum: "$ctv" },
            perc:{$multiply:[{$divide:["$ctv","$count"]},100]},
            weight: { $divide: [ "$ctv", "$count"] },
            details: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
```

It gives the error "The $multiply accumulator is a unary operator".  Similarly if I remove the line with $multiply I get "The $divide accumulator is a unary operator" on the subsequent line.  I cannot find a description for this error on the Net. What's wrong in my sintax?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [arithmetic operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators) cannot be used as **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators). Move them to another **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline stage as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "checkType": "$_id.checkType", "resultCode": "$_id.resultCode" },
        "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
        "ctv": { "$sum": "$ctv" },
        "details": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
    } },
    { "$project": {
        "count": 1,
        "details": 1,
        "ctv": 1,
        "perc": { "$multiply": [ { "$divide": ["$ctv","$count"] }, 100 ] },
        "weight": { "$divide": ["$ctv", "$count"] },
    } }
])
```

or

if using MongoDB 3.4 and above, use **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)** instead of **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "checkType": "$_id.checkType", "resultCode": "$_id.resultCode" },
        "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
        "ctv": { "$sum": "$ctv" },
        "details": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "perc": { "$multiply": [ { "$divide": ["$ctv","$count"] }, 100 ] },
        "weight": { "$divide": ["$ctv", "$count"] },
    } }
])
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have just realized that they used "unary operator" as the contrary of "group operator".  A message saying "$multiply is not a group operator" would be much clearer.

Comment: rather than addFields just to multiply at the group level, isn't it easier to just so sum then multiply in the group operation? e.g. something like { $sum: { $multiply: ["$ctv", "$count"] } }